# ValueError: too many values to unpack dealing with csv file

Tags: python, file, csv

I have the following [code](https://gist.github.com/monajalal/fc2f86736833d4525f38abe5832c38ac):

```
1 import gensim
  2 import nltk
  3 from gensim.models import word2vec
  4 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  5 from nltk.corpus import wordnet
  6 import logging
  7 import re
  8 import itertools
  9 import glob
 10 from collections import defaultdict
 11 import csv
 12 from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
 13 import os
 14 import os.path
 15 
 16 stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
 17 
 18 path = "/home/mona/computer_vision/imgur/tiny_comments/*.txt"
 19 files = glob.glob(path)
 20 csv_file_complete = open("tiny_graph.csv", "wb")
 21 stat_csv_file = open("tiny_stat.csv", "r")
 22 csv_reader = csv.reader(stat_csv_file)
 23 lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
 24 list_of_rows = []
 25 
 26 with open('swear_words_uniq.txt') as swear_words_file:
 27     swear_words = swear_words_file.read()
 28     swear_words = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", ' ', swear_words).lower().split()
 29 swear_words_file.close()
30 
 31 
 32 for file1, file2 in itertools.combinations(files, 2):
 33     with open(file1) as f1:
 34         f1_text = f1.read()
 35         f1_text = re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '',f1_text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
 36         f1_words = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", ' ', f1_text).lower().split()
 37         lemmatized_f1_words = [str(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, wordnet.VERB)) for w in f1_words if w not in stopwords]
 38         cleaned_f1_words = [w for w in lemmatized_f1_words if w not in swear_words and len(w) > 2]
 39     f1.close()
 40     with open(file2) as f2:
 41         f2_text = f2.read()
 42         f2_words = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", ' ', f2_text).lower().split()
 43         lemmatized_f2_words = [str(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, wordnet.VERB)) for w in f2_words if w not in stopwords]
 44         cleaned_f2_words = [w for w in lemmatized_f2_words if w not in swear_words and len(w) > 2]
 45     f2.close()
 46     f1_head, f1_tail = os.path.split(file1)
 47     f2_head, f2_tail = os.path.split(file2)
 48     tail_to_numbers = {ftail: fnum for fnum, ftail in csv_reader}
 49     stat_csv_file.seek(0)
50     try:
 51         file1_file_number = tail_to_numbers[f1_tail]
 52         file2_file_number = tail_to_numbers[f2_tail]
 53     except KeyError as e:
 54         print(e)
 55         continue
 56     else:
 57         row_complete = [file1_file_number.strip(), file2_file_number.strip()]
 58         list_of_rows.append(row_complete)
 59         print(len(list_of_rows))
 60 a_complete = csv.writer(csv_file_complete, delimiter=',')
 61 for row in list_of_rows:
 62     print(row)
 63     a_complete.writerow(row)
 64 
 65 csv_file_complete.close()
```

And I get this error:

```
$ python test_tiny.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_tiny.py", line 48, in <module>
    tail_to_numbers = {ftail: fnum for fnum, ftail in csv_reader}
  File "test_tiny.py", line 48, in <dictcomp>
    tail_to_numbers = {ftail: fnum for fnum, ftail in csv_reader}
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

The first 5 lines of tiny_stat.csv looks like this:

```
$ head -5 tiny_stat.csv 
1,002qtwH.txt,bed,47%,dog,55%
2,0066Z9W.txt,person,57%
3,0082B22.txt,
4,008BdUz.txt,train,68%
5,00c5Zm8.txt,train,61%,car,59%,car,58%
```

in tiny_graph.csv, I want to create lines like this:
1, 80

where 1 and 80 are the files numbers of the text files opened which I find their numbers from tiny_stat.csv.

Comment: The error says you have too many values to unpack. Each line has up to eight columns. You are trying to unpack each line into two values. Is it such a mystery?

Comment: so is it possible to do this in python2 if I have arbitrary number of columns? Thanks for explanation. This code works when I have fixed number of columns hence I was very confused

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 each line doesn't have six columns. Some lines have up to 20 columns!

Comment: Right, and you're unpacking them into two values. I'm a little puzzled about why and how you thought that would work.

Comment: ok I only care about the first two which is file number and filename

Comment: So just extract them `{row[1]: row[0] for row in csv_reader}`. In Py3 you can also do  `{ftail: fnum for fnum, ftail, *_ in csv_reader}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `{ftail: fnum for fnum, ftail in csv_reader}`

To `{row[1]: row[0] for row in csv_reader}`